# Mysql query like number greater than x

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a field for comments used to store the title of the item sold on the site as well as the bid number (bid_id). Unfortunately, the bid_id is not stored on its own in that table.

I want to query items that have a number (the bid_id) greater than 4,000 for example.

So, what I have is:

```
select * from mysql_table_name where comment like '< 4000'
```

I know this won't work, but I need something similar that works.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: well it's high time to strip that number into its own column now isn't it :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get your bid_id column cleaned up. Then index is.

```
create table `prior`
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    comments text not null
);
insert `prior` (comments) values ('asdfasdf adfas d d 93827363'),('mouse cat 12345678');
alter table `prior` add column bid_id int; -- add a nullable int column
select * from `prior`; -- bid_id is null atm btw
update `prior` set bid_id=right(comments,8); -- this will auto-cast to an int
select * from `prior`; 
+----+-----------------------------+----------+
| id | comments                    | bid_id   |
+----+-----------------------------+----------+
|  1 | asdfasdf adfas d d 93827363 | 93827363 |
|  2 | mouse cat 12345678          | 12345678 |
+----+-----------------------------+----------+
```

Create the index:

```
CREATE INDEX `idxBidId` ON `prior` (bid_id); -- or unique index
```

Comment: Works great! And no more mess :)

Comment: Geez don't award the points to me, I just slapped an ugly dump up there :p

Comment: Why do you not want the point? This is what I did (next comment)

Comment: select * from table_transactions where amount < 0 and confirmations = 0 and right(comment,6) BETWEEN 65000 AND 85000

Comment: And now I have a fix to create the new bid_id and import the id's into it

Comment: Well I am happy for a point but I didn't spend much time on it. So you are all set?

Comment: Yes, I've grabbed the data I needed. Thanks!
I also will be fixing the table to add the new column to it once I finish the little fixes I'm doing now :).

Answer (score 1):

There *is* nothing ready that works like that.

You could write a custom function or [loadable UDF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-udf.html), but it would be a significant work, with significant impact on the database. Then you could run `WHERE GET_BID_ID(comment) < 4000`.

What you *can* do more easily is devise some way of extracting the `bid_id` using [available string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html).

For example if the `bid_id` is always in the last ten characters, you can extract those, and replace all characters that are not digits with nil. What is left is the `bid_id`, and *that* you can compare.

Of course you need a complex expression with `LENGTH()`, `SUBSTRING()`, and `REPLACE()`. If the bid_id is between easily recognizable delimiters, then perhaps `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` is more your friend.

But better still... add an INTEGER column, initialize it to null, *then* store there the extracted `bid_id`. Or zero if you're positive there's no `bid_id`. Having data stored in mixed contexts is evil (and a known SQL antipattern to boot). Once you have the column available, you can select every few seconds a small number of items with `new_bid_id` still NULL and subject those to extraction, thereby gradually amending the database without overloading the system.

## In practice

This is the same approach one would use with more complicated cases. We start by **checking** what we have (this is a test table)

```
SELECT commento FROM arti LIMIT 3;

+-----------------------------------------+
| commento                                |
+-----------------------------------------+
| This is the first comment 100 200 42500 |
| Another 7 Q 32768                       |
| And yet another 200 15 55332            |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

So we need the last characters:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(commento, LENGTH(commento)-5) FROM arti LIMIT 3;
+-----------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING(commento, LENGTH(commento)-5) |
+-----------------------------------------+
|  42500                                  |
|  32768                                  |
|  55332                                  |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

This **looks** good but it is not; there's an extra space left before the ID. So 5 doesn't work, SUBSTRING is 1-based. No matter; we just use 4.

...and we're done.

```
mysql> SELECT commento FROM arti WHERE SUBSTRING(commento, LENGTH(commento)-4) < 40000;
+-------------------+
| commento          |
+-------------------+
| Another 7 Q 32768 |
+-------------------+

mysql> SELECT commento FROM arti WHERE SUBSTRING(commento, LENGTH(commento)-4) BETWEEN 35000 AND 55000;
+-----------------------------------------+
| commento                                |
+-----------------------------------------+
| This is the first comment 100 200 42500 |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

The problem is if you have a number not of the same length (e.g. 300 and 131072). Then you need to take a slice large enough for the larger number, and if the number is short, you will get maybe "1 5 300" in your slice. That's where `SUBSTRING_INDEX` comes to the rescue: by capturing seven characters, from " 131072" to "1 5 300", the ID will always be *in the last space separated token of the slice*.

**IN THIS LAST CASE**, when numbers are not of the same length, you will find a problem. The extracted IDs are not numbers at all - to MySQL, they are **strings**. Which means that they are compared in lexicographic, not numerical, order; and "17534" is considered **smaller** than "202", just like "Alice" comes before "Bob". To overcome this you need to cast the string as unsigned integer, which further slows down the operations.

```
WHERE CAST( SUBSTRING(...) AS UNSIGNED) < 4000
```

Comment: Thanks for such a great answer! The bid_id I want to query is between 65000 and 8500 (there are only around 100 entries there as there are other conditions to be met as well) so it's always the last 6 characters in the field.
The field example below:
Refund: eGift card newegg.com $50 49798

Would you mind showing me an example query to check the last 6 characters?

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from mysql_table_name where substring(comment,start,length, signed integer) < 4000
```

This will work, but I suggest create new column and put the bid value in it then compare.

To update value in new column you can use

```
update table set newcol = substring(comment,start,length)
```

Hope this will help